# How to send app invites to instagram followers?

Tags: instagram

I am pretty new with iOS 7 .
I am using [parse](http://parse.com) and in my app using login with instagram.

I want to send app invites(or notifications) to instagram followers (Same as we do in facebook).

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contact information available for a instagram follower, so you cannot invite instagram users like in facebook, you can however comment on a user's photo and hope that they read it.